# Permalinks are not working in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks

I deployed My Wordpress Blog in one of my subdomains in Digital Ocean.
I am running apache2 as my webserver.

**.htaccess** file related to my WordPress installation:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
```

Virtual host file related to Wordpress Site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.gopibabu.live
    ServerAlias www.blog.gopibabu.live

    DocumentRoot /var/www/MyBlog

        <Directory /var/www/MyBlog>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.gopibabu.live [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.blog.gopibabu.live
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

When I am trying to change my permalink settings to settings other than plain(Only plain setting is working), I am getting 404 Page

[404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYQEN.png)

Can any one help to fix this problem?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite installed on your server? If not, check this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Yes, It is enabled!!!